# How to undo SetFile -a V?

Tags: finder, time-machine

I used SetFile -a V "/Volumes/Backup di Time Machine"/ to get rid off the time machine's icon on the desktop but it seems that I don't see it in the finder too and Time Machine stops working, it can't find the drive!
So how to undo this?
Thanks

P.S. stay away from this devil trick ;)

Comment: I found the solution. Just type the attribute `V` lowercase and restart the Finder!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Just type the attribute V lowercase and restart the Finder!:)